# generate nested number sequences R-style

Tags: r, vectorization, lapply

I need to generate number sequences as follows:

1
1,2
1,2,3
...
1,2,3...,n
2
2,3
2,3,4
...
2,3,4,...,n
...
...
n-1
n-1,n
n

I come from other programming languages where loops are perfectly fine. But I understand the R community favors the so-called vectorized operations rather than loops (more efficient, although I haven't read all the details on the why is this).

So, the first thing that comes to my mind for what I need to do was loops. And I wrote this code that certainly does the job (R gurus say euhh in 3,2,1...)

```
n <- 30
accum <- list()
for (x in 1:n) {
    for (y in x:n) {
        accum[[paste(x,y)]] <- x:y
    }
}
```

But this is ugly code (and I guess non-efficient).

So, what is the clever R-style code for my problem?

I certainly haven't mastered vectorized operations and the apply family functions. But my best shot at this was:

```
n <- 30
accum <- lapply(1:n, FUN = function(x){lapply(x:n, FUN = seq, from = x)})
```

no idea if this is good R-style coding, but it *almost* get the job done. The problem with this solution is that it produces a list with `n` elements, which are also lists and contain the sequences. But what I wanted was a list with 465 elements (in case of n=30), so one element per sequence without all the nesting of lists that this solution produces.

I would really appreciate solutions that are clever and elegant in the R world.

Comment: For you second solution, `unlist(accum, rec=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

To get a single vector:

```
n <- 4
u <- sequence(n:1)
(v <- sequence(u) + rep(1:n, rev(cumsum(1:n))) - 1)
# [1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 2 2 3 2 3 4 3 3 4 4
```

and a list of vectors:

```
split(v, rep(cumsum(u), u))
```

or something very similar to your solution:

```
Reduce('c', lapply(1:n, function(x) lapply(x:n, seq, from = x)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I split the sequences in this solution? (as far as I can tell, this solution produces a vector with all the sequences appended one after another). I wanted every sequence as an element in a list to, later, lapply a function to each sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You second solution is good. All you have to do is `unlist` one layer.

```
unlist(lapply(1:n, FUN = function(x) lapply(x:n, FUN = seq, from = x)), rec=FALSE)
```

What you have here is the list monad in disguise. To make that more clear, consider the following, which is equivalent

```
mapcat <- function(x,f,...) unlist(lapply(x,f,...),rec=FALSE)
mapcat(1:n,function(a) mapcat(a:n, function(b) list(seq(a,b))))
```

Here `mapcat` is the bind operation, and `list` is the unit/return.

In languages with the do-notation for list monads, this could be written, for example in Haskell, as

```
do
  a <- [1..n]
  b <- [a..n]
  return([a..b])
```

I don't know of any R package with such sugar implemented, but using the `foreach` library, we can get closer

```
library(foreach)
foreach(a=1:n, .combine='c') %:% foreach(b=a:n) %do% seq(a,b)
```